# MVC optimization using ScriptBundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following script bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryBootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js","~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                     "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
    #if DEBUG
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

in web.config

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

when i run the application in debug, there is no problem but when i run in release mode i got the error:

> jqueryBootstrap:17 -- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Any idea

Comment: How do you call your bundle? @Scripts.Render or @Styles.Render? Can you show us your code?

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryBootstrap")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you
Somehow when i removed `"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"` to separate bundle it worked fine.